# (Semi-)Riemannian geometry for working PDE analysts

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, semi-riemannian-geometry

> What is a good reference on (semi-)Riemannian geometry written for PDE analysts (that is, with main focus on analytical problems and approaches)?

The closest thing I know to this, are two books by Thierry Aubin, but I'm looking for some more pointers to the literature.

Comment: Are you interested in exposition of standard topics, or pointers to current research?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Both actually.

Comment: That’s a pretty broad request. Anything you’re particularly interested in?

Comment: Here's one example. In this [conference proceedings issue](http://iopscience.iop.org/issue/1742-6596/968/1), you'll find several papers on current analytical problems in low regularity Lorentzian geometries.

Comment: @DeaneYang I've asked about the more specific issue of geodesic connectedness in a previous question of mine. Now I actually wonder about 1. more basic issues and 2. advanced topics related to PDEs.